# expression for infinite series with powers of factorial in denominator

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, asymptotics

The series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\exp(c k \beta)}{(k!)^\beta} $$
has come up when I'm trying to apply the methodology in this paper (http://www.ism.ac.jp/~eguchi/pdf/Robustify_MLE.pdf) to Poisson regression.

When $\beta = 1,$ it is $e^{e^c}$ and when $\beta = 2,$ it is $I_0(2e^c),$ the modified Bessel function of the first kind, but have no idea what happens at other values, or how to approach the question.

Does this series have either a closed form expression in terms of special functions, or an asymptotic expansion that is numerically useful for $\beta \in [1, 5]$ and $|c| < R$?

Comment: This sum was discussed in the book "Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers" by Carl M. Bender and Steven A Orszag in section 6.7 Example 4. The result is (with $x=exp(c \beta)$) $(2 \pi)^{(1-\beta)/2} \beta^{-1/2} x^{(1-\beta)/(2 \beta)} exp(\beta x^{1/\beta})$.

Comment: The "result" in my above comment means the asymptotic expansion of the sum for large $x$.

Comment: ... and of course I would have to have given away my copy of Bender and Orszag :). If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Buy one from Amazon ? Google ? However, I put my comment as an answer. Maybe you can accept it anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I copied this from my comments above:

This sum was discussed in the book "Advanced Mathematical Methods for Scientists and Engineers" by Carl M. Bender and Steven A Orszag in section 6.7 Example 4. The asymptotic result is (with $x=\exp(c \beta)$)  $(2 \pi)^{(1-\beta)/2} \beta^{-1/2} x^{(1-\beta)/(2\beta)}\exp(\beta x^{1/\beta})$.

**Edit**: Sketch of a proof following Bender's & Orszag's lines: Let us look at a somewhat simpler sum
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{k}}{k!^{\beta}}.
$$
By examining the ratio of two consecutive terms of this sum we find that the terms are increasing until $k=k_{max}:=\lfloor x^{1/\beta}\rfloor$ and then decreasing. Using Stirling's formula and relaxing the requirement of $k$ being integer, we can expand $k!$ around $k_{0}$ by inserting $k=x^{1/\beta}+t$
$$
k! \sim x^{k/\beta} \exp(-x^{1/\beta}+t^{2}x^{-1/\beta}/2) \sqrt{2 \pi} x^{1/(2 \beta)}
$$
for large $x$ and small $t$, i.e. $t^{3}\ll x^{2/\beta}$, which let us neglect higher terms in $t$. We find that the terms are sharply peaked for $k$ around $k_{0}$. Approximate the sum over $k$ by an integral over $t$, with the integration range extended to the whole real axis. (We can do this since the additional contributions to the integral are negligible.) Evaluating the integral gives the result.

**Edit**: Getting higher orders for any real $\beta$ is straight forward but tedious with the above (Laplace-) method. However, going after chapter 5.11 in Luke's "The Special Functions and their Approximation", Vol. 1, one can give a rather compact formula for any order, when restricting $\beta$ to positive integers. Actually, it is the asymptotic expansion of the hypergeometric function $_{0}F_{\beta-1}(;1,...,1;\exp(c \beta))$, which is the same as the OP's sum. Write $x=\exp(c \beta)$. Then
$$
_{0}F_{\beta-1}(;1,...,1;x)= (2 \pi)^{(1-\beta)/2} \beta^{-1/2} \exp(\beta x^{1/\beta}) x^{\frac{1}{2 \beta}-\frac{1}{2}} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k} \beta^{-k} x^{-k/\beta}
$$
where $c_{k}$ is recursively defined as
$$
c_{k}=\frac{1}{\beta k} \sum_{s=1}^{\beta-1} c_{k-s} \sum_{r=0}^{s}\frac{(-1)^{s-r}}{r!(s-r)!} (r+k+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\beta}{2})^{\beta}
$$ 
and $c_{0}=1$, $c_{k}=0$ for $k<0$.

I checked the formula with Mathematica for several values of $\beta$ and orders and it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

If $\beta$ is an integer $\ge 3$, it can be written as a hypergeometric
$$ \mbox{$_0$F$_{\beta-1}$}(\ ;\, 1,\ldots,1;,\exp(c\beta))$$
where there are $\beta-1$ ones.

Comment: I think what you are saying is that this is how the hypergeometric is _defined_, but this does not really shed a huge amount of light on the matter :)

Comment: I agree, it does not by itself shed a lot of light on the matter, but it does provide a name that can be looked up.  For example, you can ask Maple's FunctionAdvisor about hypergeom([],[1,1,1],t).  In this case, you'll find a differential equation ${\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{t}^{4}}}f \left( t \right) =-6\,{\frac {{
\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{t}^{3}}}f \left( t \right) }{t}}-7\,{
\frac {{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{t}^{2}}}f \left( t \right) }{{t}^{
2}}}-{\frac {{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}t}}f \left( t \right) }{{t}^{3}}}+{
\frac {f \left( t \right) }{{t}^{3}}}
$

Comment: Can the original series in the OP be written as a differential equation for non-integer $\beta$? I'm interested in integral representations or representations as a DE for this series.

Comment: I don't know of any differential equation that works for non-integer $\beta$.  It seems unlikely that there could be a linear DE with rational-function coefficients.